# Can you prevent UI update of other JSX element on store update?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

if u have react component

If JSX_OF_ONELEMENT updates due to store change, my whole component updates. 
Due to which selection I made in MaterialTable vanish.

So is it possible that  on update, only JSX_OF_ONELEMENT updates and it doesnt re-render whole component.

Okay, thanks.

Comment: Try ```useMemo``` with dependencies for the component that does not want to rerender unnecessarily.  https://usehooks.com/useMemo/ . If that doesn't works please add some more code in the question to figure out.

Comment: @NiyasNazar Im using class based component.

Comment: Maybe you can separate the component that you need to prevent rerendering as a functional component.

Comment: @NiyasNazar i will give it a go, and get back. thanks for your time.